# Find adjacent groups in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find how many large groups are in a string s.
A small group is simply a contiguous segment(same character repeats).
A large group is a contiguous segment formed from 2 or more small groups.

It`s clearer with code,below I get all the small groups

```js
var s = "ccccoodeffffiiighhhhhhhhhhttttttts";

sgroups= s.match(/(.)\1+/g);
console.log(sgroups)
```

How do I find the large groups?

```
"ccccoo",
 "ffffiii",
 "hhhhhhhhhhttttttt"
```

In another example

```js
var s = "soooooldieeeeeer";
var sgroups= s.match(/(.)\1+/g);
console.log(sgroups)
```

In the code above,since the 2 small groups are not contiguous in the original string,there are no large groups.

Comment: Is "g" in your example a small group? Your regex suggests that it is not, because a character needs to occur at least twice. Also, is a large group exactly two consecutive small groups, or at least? Because that is not what you suggest now. Finally, for the string "fffooobbb", is that as a whole a large group? Or is it "fffooo" and "ooobbb" only? Or can the large groups not overlap?

Comment: @Justastudent No overlap and at least 2 consecutive small groups.g is not a small group,at least 2 in length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use:

```js
var rx = /(?:(.)\1+(?!\1)){2,}/g;
console.log("soooooldieeeeeer".match(rx));
console.log("soooooldieeeeeerrr".match(rx));
```

**Details**:

- `(?:` - start of  a non-capturing group (does not create a numbered capture for us to be able to still use `\1` backreference later and keep the match "clean")

  - `(.)` - capturing group 1 matching any char  (but a line break char)
  - `\1+`  - one or more occurrences of the same char as stored in Group 1 (where `\1` is the backreference to the value kept in Group 1 and `+` is a *one or more occurrences* quantifier)
  - `(?!\1)` - makes sure the chunk of identical characters is not followed with the same char, so as not to allow backtracking match strings where 4 or more consecutive identical characters appear.
- `){2,}` - two or more occurrences of the non-capturing group pattern.

Comment: If I try it with 'soooooldieeeeeer' it returns me ['ooooo', 'eeeeee'] but it should return no match since they are not contigous.

Comment: Please add this requirement to the question.